# Is there any limit of user access in GlassFish Server

Tags: glassfish

We have deployed our application in GlassFish server. I was asked how may connections are possible in GlassFish server concurrently. Can we set it also ? I am new in GlassFish server, so it will be a great help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish does not have a hard-defined limit on the number of concurrent connections. It is going to depend on your hardware, tuning, and what you mean by "concurrent". A good place to start is the Performance Tuning Guide at [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/index.htm).